# Parsoid test page fail during VisualEditor installation

Tags: mediawiki, visual-editor, parsoid

I'm trying to install VisualEditor in my MediaWiki wiki but I get stuck when I test Parsoid.

This is the result of the test page:

```
error: No API URI available for prefix: enwiki; domain: undefined path: /_rt/mediawikiwiki/Parsoid
Error: No API URI available for prefix: enwiki; domain: undefined
    at /usr/lib/parsoid/src/lib/config/MWParserEnvironment.js:295:10
    at /usr/lib/parsoid/node_modules/prfun/lib/index.js:532:26
    at tryCatch2 (/usr/lib/parsoid/node_modules/babybird/lib/promise.js:48:12)
    at PrFunPromise.Promise (/usr/lib/parsoid/node_modules/babybird/lib/promise.js:458:15)
    at new PrFunPromise (/usr/lib/parsoid/node_modules/prfun/lib/index.js:57:21)
    at /usr/lib/parsoid/node_modules/prfun/lib/index.js:530:18
    at tryCatch1 (/usr/lib/parsoid/node_modules/babybird/lib/promise.js:40:12)
    at promiseReactionJob (/usr/lib/parsoid/node_modules/babybird/lib/promise.js:269:19)
    at PromiseReactionJobTask.call (/usr/lib/parsoid/node_modules/babybird/lib/promise.js:284:3)
    at flush (/usr/lib/parsoid/node_modules/babybird/node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
```

I set the API in the settings.js file end to make sure it is correct I tested using the curl command. And it works.
But I still have the problem.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You would've put something like this in Parsoid's localsettings.js:

`parsoidConfig.setInterwiki( 'localhost', 'http://mediawiki.krenair.dev/mediawiki_dev/w/api.php' );`
(example from my dev wiki setup)

That first string (in my case, 'localhost') should be identical to the value VE is set to use by `$wgVisualEditorParsoidPrefix` in your wiki's LocalSettings.php (unless you're using some other system to configure that stuff like VirtualRestConfig, in which case I can probably help in the comments). I believe you currently have it set to 'enwiki' for some reason, or else something is going wrong leading parsoid to default to 'enwiki' (I really don't know why they consider that a sane default).